# Why doesn't apollo store update?

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have the following query

```
const ITEM_COMMENTS_QUERY = gql`
  query Search($id: UUID, $per_page: Int) {
    item(id: $id) {
      id
      comments(page: 1, per_page: $per_page) {
        edges {
          id
          author {
            id
            first_name
            last_name
          }
          content
        }
        total_count
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

and the following mutation

```
  const CREATE_COMMENT_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation create_comment($id: UUID!, $content: String!) {
    create_comment(id: $id, content: $content, type: COMMENT_TYPE_ITEM) {
      id
      ... on ItemComment {
        item {
          id
          comments(page: 1, per_page: 100) {
            edges {
              id
              author {
                id
                first_name
                last_name
              }
              content
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

and the response is correct, but apollo store doesn't update.
(I have dataIdFromObject: `elm => elm.id`)

[image: response]

Answer (score 1):

The Apollo Client only updates the store on update mutations. So when you use create or delete mutations you need to tell Apollo Client how to update. I had expected the store to update automatically but it doesn't...

Following an update/delete mutation, you'll need to update the store using the `update` or `refetch` commands - [see documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html). Here's an `update` example [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534453/apollo-client-react-update-on-create-mutation-cant-find-field-fund-o/45536592?noredirect=1#comment78035918_45536592) and